# messy fitted line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels

I generated some data y with linear relationship to log(x). I put y and x in a dataframe, sorted by the value of x, fitted model,  and then tried to plot data points along with fitted line. However, what I got was a very messy fitted line. I must have done something wrong.  This can be easily done in R, but with statsmodels.... I still cannot figure out why. Help needed. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
B0 = 3
B1 = 0.5
X = np.random.rand(1000)
epsilon = np.random.normal(0,0.1, size=1000)
y=B0 + B1*np.log(X)+epsilon
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Y':y, 'X':X})
df1.sort_values('X', inplace=True)
model1 = smf.ols ('Y~np.log(X)', data=df1).fit()

plt.scatter(df1.X, df1.Y)
plt.plot(df1.X, model1.predict(np.log(df1.X)), 'r-')
```

This is what I got:

[image]

Comment: something is messing up the index for the prediction. This might be a bug in the index handling. Avoiding pandas and patsy in predict produces a good looking plot.

Comment: Don't pass log(X) into predict, just pass in X.  When you fit a model with a formula, the design matrix for prediction is reconstructed from the new X (if provided, as it is here).

Comment: There is a bug in statsmodels master and current maintenance 0.8 (since August) when the index is not sorted. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3409